# How to access _pycache_ directory

Tags: python, bash

I want to remove a folder, but I can’t get in *pycache* to delete the `pyc` and pyo$ files. I have done it before, but I don’t know how I did it.

Comment: Can you share your code so far? Do you get an error or anything?

Comment: Please post your code, even if it doesn't work. It'll help us help you faster

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your `python` file artifacts, such as the `.pyc` and `.pyo` cache files, maybe you could try the following:

1. Move into your project's root directory

   `cd <path_to_project_root>`
2. Remove python file artifacts

   `find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm -f {} +
   find . -name '*.pyo' -exec rm -f {} +`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have a subdirectory under my home directory that I wish to delete. I have deleted all the files except for the _pycache_ directory. When I try to delete _pycache_ , bash tells me No such file or directory. In the past, somehow, I did something simple by mistake that let me get into _pycache_ and delete its contents. My question is, what did I do?

Comment: Perhaps it's already deleted and your terminal or gui hasn't reflected that. Can you try reopening your home directory and seeing if the __pycache__ directory still exists? If it does try a rm -rf __pycache__